# Is it possible to use BIM360 Team (formerly A360) commenting and markup tools in Forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge

BIM 360 Team has a nice built-in commenting tool that tracks issues. Is it possible if we can use the exact same feature inside Forge Viewer API? (my question may sound convoluted because I'm not a software engineer..) For any one who doesn't know the feature, please see below article. Any help is much appreciated.

https://blog.a360.autodesk.com/a360-release-enhanced-commenting-and-markup-tools/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely possible. The Autodesk development teams make use of Forge web services to implement A360 features. You have access to the same web services. You may even be able to peruse and analyse their code in the JavaScript debugger to see how they implement the client side user interface on top of the server side web service. In this case, the web service being used is the Issues API. More on that topic here:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/11/bim-360-docs-issues-forge-devday-and-accelerator.html#5

Comment: I see. Bit of reinventing-the-wheel effort (using Issues API in BIM360 APIs) is inevitable if one wishes to use BIM360 Commeting/MarkUp feature OUTSIDE of BIM360 standalone package and in Forge API environment. Thank you Jeremy!